# Php last day of the month in the Hijri calendar

Tags: php, calendar, hijri

We have such data in hand. The last day of the month in the Hijri calendar. How do I get it?

```
1437-03-21
1437-03-22
1437-03-23
1437-03-24
1437-03-25
1437-03-26
1437-03-27
1437-03-28
1437-03-29
1437-03-30
1437-04-01
1437-04-02
1437-04-03
1437-04-04
1437-04-05
1437-04-06
1437-04-07
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure there's an algorithm for that which can easily be found via your favourite search engine.

Comment: @m02ph3u5 Unfortunately I can't find :(

Answer (score -1):

Try to use HijriDateLib http://github.com/hubaishan/hijridatelib
use function calendar\days_in_month

```
<?php
require_once('hijri.class.php');
echo (new hijri\Calendar()).days_in_month(3,1437);
?>
```